# Git: Why can't I see another "branch" of the commit tree?

Tags: git

I say "branch" in quotes because I mean branch in the data-structure, graph topology sense, not a git branch which is something like a handle to a particular commit.

I am on master, I created a new branch with a commit which I made from editing an earlier commit: (Alphabet order = chronological order, basically I found the bug was first introduced in commit C)

```
A -- B -- C -- D <-- master
      \
       E <-- bugfix_branch
```

I am on the `master` branch and I look at the little tree diagram in `gitk` and it does not show me commit E. Similarly if I checkout `bugfix_branch` branch and look there it shows me in the list only the commits A, B, and E (so I don't see C or D).

I'd like to view a more complete view of my entire git history without having to first push to  bitbucket or github to try to look at the graphs there. Is there some kind of way to view all the commits and see which commits are children of which?

Comment: What are you using to see "the little tree diagram"? Gitk?

Comment: Did you try : git rev-list --all

Comment: @pyfunc that just gives me a linear list of commits. Doesn't help me get a better understanding of the tree structure.

Comment: Yes. I was not thinking of the visualization at all. gitk is a good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I use to get a pretty printed tree in my terminal with all the nodes.

```
log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative --all
```

You can add this to your `.gitconfig` file, I have this in "~/.gitconfig":

```
[alias]
    lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

Which lets me do:

```
git lg --all
```

(Disclaimer I modified the code from some other source, but I can't remember where...)

Comment: Holy crap this is flippin' sweet. I may need to switch my accept to this. This is some proper ASCII ownage right here. Oh and the colors! :)

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for making this easier to invoke? Anything more elegant than a `alias gitg='git log --graph --pretty=....'`?

Comment: You can add it to your git aliases file. Added details to the answer.

Comment: It's cool you added that disclaimer. I don't mind if you didn't "come up with" the command yourself (if we wanna get pedantic the original authors of the functionality actually came up with it). The goal of this site is to collect awesome bits of knowledge that help us all get our work done faster, better, (stronger) and this is about as perfect an example as you can get: I can view a perfect little ASCII tree-graph on ANY ssh terminal I can run git on. I can tell you for sure I am gonna make use of this command when I run git on my JB'd iPad3 (I have been using the Prompt app).

Comment: Crud. Git from Cydia is version 1.5.6rc0 and it can't handle some of these colors.

Answer (score 5):

Because you need to use `gitk --all`. `gitk` only will show only the current branch.

Comment: Speaking of which, there is a nice way of seeing every commit from the repository (even the ones that will be garbage collected): `gitk --all $(git reflog --pretty=format:%h)`

Comment: I added `alias gitk='gitk --all'` in my custom bash profile script.

Answer (score 4):

> I am on the master branch and I look at the little tree diagram in gitk

You need to start gitk with `--all`. For example, from bash:

```
gitk --all
```

From [the documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitk.html):

> --all
>
> Show all branches.

Comment: I'm gonna up vote you and accept the other guy because you have plenty of points (compared to him) even though your answer is slightly more complete

Comment: Oh, you are a nice guy, @StevenLu. :)

Comment: @StevenLu Seriously??? You should be accepting the answer that's most complete, and not worrying about who has how many points. That way, when people look up answers, they find "the most complete" answer.

Comment: That said: There's nothing wrong with upvoting @Yuri's answer. I just question the approach and justification.

Comment: @DavidMakogon You have a valid point. It's all moot because I think Michael Anderson's answer is so much better because it works on the terminal (!!) Sorry YuriAlbuquerque.